# Sharing kitchen hood and kitchen ventilation through one duct

Tags: kitchens, ceiling-fan, ventilation, ducts, hood

My kitchen currently does not have a kitchen hood, so I'm planning to install it. At the moment there is a ventilation duct, my idea is to connect the hood pipe to the ventilation pipe in the drop ceiling so I don't need ductwork on the exterior wall for the hood. Is this OK or there is the need for having two separate ducts?

[image]

Comment: When the hood fan would be on it would blow down into the ventilation duct and into the living space. I don't think you can join these. Is the ventilation duct to expel air from the living space or to bring fresh air in?

Comment: The ventilation duct is to expel air from the kitchen space, it goes to the roof (top floor flat), that's why I thought it's possible to share the same duct.

Comment: Does the existing vent duct have a fan and if so is it at the bottom or at the top?

Comment: It has a fan at the bottom (currently not working).

Comment: You would have to check with building management and building inspection. I would bet that you cannot have both.

Comment: I wonder if the OP could share his results. I am thinking of the same solution, except that I have the opposite situation: I have the kitchen hood already, and would like to add a kitchen/dining room ventilation.